# What would be the best way to isolate these squares?

Tags: python, opencv

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/) , but the problem is, my squares have illustrations on it, which causes opencv to pick up on those as well. At least, I think that's what the problem is.

Original image:

[image]

I am aware this might work better with a black background but this is all I have to work with for now.

This is the result of my attempt:

[image]

windows, python2, opencv3.3-dev

Comment: 1-convert image to gray (`cv2.cvtColor()`). 2-threshold the gray image to get binary image (`cv2.threshold()`). 3-find contours of all shapes in the binary image (`cv2.findContours()`). 4-find bounding box of each contour found (`cv2.minAreaRect()`). 5-compute area of each rectangle (`width*height`). 6-remove rectangles with area greater than some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Try to process the `S` channel in `HSV` space like this.

1. convert to hsv
2. seperate the s-channel
3. threshold the s-channel
4. some other post-process(such as morph-op)

[image]